# Military sci-fi: warrior-spy codenamed GENIE, Greatest Effectiveness Nexus Identification and Elimination fights mercenaries

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, military-sf

Trying to find story that I read years ago. I really wanted to reread it again.

Setting:
A remote planet hires a mercenary general to help defend it from an impending invasion by a much larger professional mercenary force.
If successful he would retire to this planet.

A doctor or EMT on this planet approaches the General and explains that he is an exile/refugee who has fled a failed/fallen Star Kingdom.
And that he was trained by that Star Kingdom as a special warrior-spy agent, just prior to the collapse of the Star Kingdom.
But he needed someone else to specifically Activate him and assign him to defend the planet from all enemies.

I remember that he referred to the acronym GENIE, which he explained was Greatest Effectiveness Nexus Identification and Elimination.
I tried various searches for this phrase but I must have remembered it wrong because I can’t find anything like it.
Pretty sure that it was something like a short story or novella.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately what year would "years ago" have been?  Where did you read this, in an anthology, a magazine or online?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150403/short-story-mercenary-general-with-a-supercomputer?

Comment: Pretty sure that I read this in the 1980s, and it may have been a Classic sci-fi story that I read for my high-school sci-fi class. No supercomputers involvement (I have read part of that series of books when it came out).

Comment: Props for getting the initialism exactly correct!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The story you are looking for is "[Shelter from the Storm](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42930)" (1982), by John M. Ford, first published in *Asimov's*, July 1982, which is where I read it.  You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v06n07_1982-07/page/n119/mode/1up).

The story is very much as you describe; the protagonist is Ross Kinbote, defense marshal of Silverburn Territory on the colony world of Perathena.

The world is in imminent danger of invasion by a mercenary company commanded by Solomon Draegar with whom Kinbote has history.  The mercenaries have nominally been hired by another world, Exathena, but the price is too high and the suspicion is that the real money comes from the Star Kings.

Dr. Alexis Teal, an offworlder who is engaged to Kinbote's daughter Claire, approaches him one night and reveals he has special skills:

> Kinbote said, "You know that in the Territory we don't ask where you're from or what you did there." Maybe Teal was a washout from an Academy or War College somewhere. Or an officer's son who couldn't follow his parent's lead, for whatever reason. Or even one of those pacifists who could not let war alone with their minds, even as their hearts abhorred it. "You must have heard of me," he added. "After Draeger at Ramalea, my record's no secret."
>
> "Mine is," Teal said, "but I'll tell you."
>
> "You were a soldier?" Elise asked.
>
> Teal smiled. "I was a secret weapon."
>
> Kinbote poured more of the golden, heady brandy.
>
> "The project,” Teal said, "was called **GENIE. Greatest Effectiveness Nexus Identification and Elimination...** though I don’t know whether the acronym was invented before or afterward.
>
> "Anyway... the idea was: what do you want to do to an enemy army?"
>
> Teal and Elise both looked at Kinbote. "Destroy its ability to fight," he said automatically.
>
> Teal nodded. "And traditionally, you do that by causing enough casualties in it to destroy its structure. Like smashing at a stone wall with a sledge until it crumbles. But there's another way to knock a wall down."
>
> Elise said, "Find the keystone."
>
> Teal said, "Find the nexi of greatest effectiveness... and eliminate them."